# How to solve an objective function having an exponential term with a different base in CVXR?

Tags: r, optimization, exponential, convex, cvxr

I am using `CVXR` to solve a concave objective function. The decision variable (`x`) is one-dimensional and the objective function is the summation of 2 logarithmic terms in which the second term is exponential with different bases of “`a` and `b`” (e.g., `a^x`, `b^x`); “`a` and `b`” are constants.

My full objective function is:

```
(-x*sum(ln(y))) + ln((1-x)/((a^(1-x))-(b^(1-x))))
```

where `y` is a given 1-D vector of data.

When I add the second term having (`a^x` and `b^x`) to the objective function, I keep getting

```
Error in a^(1 - x): non-numeric argument to binary operator
```

Is there any atom function in `CVXR` that can be used to code `constant^x`?
Here is my code:

```
library(CVXR)
a <- 7
b <- 0.3
M=1000
x_i # is a given vector of 1-D data

x <- Variable(1)
nominator <- (1-x)
denominator <- (1/((a^(1-x))-(b^(1-x))))
obj <- (-xsum(log(x_i)) + Mlog(nominator/denominator)) # change M to the length of X_i later
constr <- list(x>0)
prob <- Problem(Maximize(obj), constr)
result <- solve(prob)
alpha_hat <- result$getValue(x)
```

Please tell me what I am doing wrong. I appreciate your help in advance.

Answer (score 0):

do some math

```
2=e^log2
2^x=(e^log2)^x=e^(log2*x)
```

So, you can try

```
denominator <- 1/(exp(log(a)*(1-x)) - exp(log(b)*(1-x)))
```

Comment: you should explain your answer. not just do some math

Comment: You need to be more careful with your markdown/formatting. https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help